# Entity Framework & Views

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to create referential integrity for views. I know its not possible in the database but using EF i am looking for a way to achieve this.

Situation is like the following:

the view (`vSkillMatch` ) has three columns: jobid, matchingskillid, candidateid.

These come from `JobDescription`, `SkillInfo`  & `Candidate` tables respectively.

from my web api I want to return  the following fields:

jobtitle, joblocation, candidatename, mobilenumber, matchingskillName

these fields are available in their respective tables.

currently i am doing like this:

**web api method**

```
public List<CandidateBySkillDTO> getCandidate() 
    {
       var SkillMatches = db.vSkillMatches;

        List<CandidateBySkillDTO> cbsDTO = new List<CandidateBySkillDTO>();

        foreach (vSkillMatch Match in SkillMatches)
        {
            CandidateSkillDTO CandidateSkillInfo = new CandidateSkillDTO(Match.CandidateId, Match.SkillId);

            CandidateBySkillDTO candidateList = new CandidateBySkillDTO();

            candidateList.candidateId = CandidateSkillInfo.candidateInfo.Id;
            candidateList.candidateMobile = CandidateSkillInfo.candidateInfo.PrimaryMobile;
            candidateList.SkillName = CandidateSkillInfo.skillInfo.SkillName;

            cbsDTO.Add(candidateList);
        }

        return cbsDTO;

    }
```

**CandidateBySkillDTO Model Class**

```
public class CandidateBySkillDTO
    {
        public int candidateId { get; set; }
        public string candidateName { get; set; }
        public long candidateMobile { get; set; }
        public string createdBy { get; set; }
        public string SkillName { get; set; }
        public int skillId { get; set; }
        public string jobTitle { get; set; }
        public string jobCreated { get; set; }

    }
```

**CandidateSkillDTO Model Class**

```
public class CandidateSkillDTO
{
    ubietydbEntities db = new ubietydbEntities();

    public int candidateId;
    public int skillId;

    public CandidateSkillDTO(int CandidateId, int SkillId)
    {
        this.candidateId = CandidateId;
        this.skillId = SkillId;
    }

    public Candidate candidateInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return db.Candidates.Find(this.candidateId);
        }

        set
        {

        }
    }

    public Skill skillInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return db.Skills.Find(this.skillId);
        }
        set
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I feel that my requirement is not very much local to my project. Is this the only way to accomplish the task or am I missing a major feature of EF to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Code-first / db-first?

Comment: You can create associations / navigation properties (`vSkillMatch.Job` etc.) in the edmx designer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole thing could be done in one single query to db (and thus potentially much faster):

```
public List<CandidateBySkillDTO> getCandidate() 
{
   return db
      .vSkillMatches
      .Select(e => new 
      {
          candidateInfo = db.Candidates.FirstOrDefault( c => c.Id == e.candidateId),
          skillInfo = db.Skills.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == e.skillId)
      })
      .Select(e => new CandidateBySkillDTO
      {
          candidateId = e.candidateInfo.Id,
          candidateMobile = e.candidateInfo.PrimaryMobile,
          SkillName = e.skillInfo.SkillName
      })
      .ToList();
}
```

Comment: thanks. i get the error `Method Find(System.Object[]) declared on type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet cannot be called with instance of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery` when i try to execute the code

Comment: I am terribly sorry, my mistake. Indeed Find cannot be translated wihtin a query. I've changed the code to use First method instead. Please try it now.

Comment: Sorry, one last change - FirstOrDefault should be used instead of First

Comment: stuff just can't get better. i am not supposed to so i am commenting  `// thank you`